# How do I conform my data model to Hashable?

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to conform my data model for messages to hashable so I can use a scroll reader to automatically scroll to the bottom of chat conversations.

However, it wasn't as simple as just adding hashable to the data model as I get two errors:

Type 'Message' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Type 'Message' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

My message data model code is below, support is much appreciated :)

```
struct Message: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let text: String
    let user: User
    let toId: String
    let fromId: String
    let isFromCurrentUser: Bool
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    let id: String
    let photoUrl: String?

    
    var timestampString: String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter.string(from: timestamp.dateValue(), to: Date()) ?? ""
    }
    
    var chatPartnerId: String { return isFromCurrentUser ? toId : fromId }
    
    init(user: User, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.user = user
        
        self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
        self.toId = dictionary["toId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.isFromCurrentUser = fromId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        self.timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date: Date())
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""
        self.photoUrl = dictionary["photoUrl"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

I tried adding Hashable to the data model but before I dig myself into a hole I thought it would be better to ask more experienced people.

Comment: You can either ensure that all types used in properties conform to `Hashable` or add a manual implementation to this type.

Comment: see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all the properties in your struct also conform to `Hashable`. You can see where the problem lies by expanding the error message in the sidebar…

[image]

So you need to make sure `User` and `Timestamp` conform to `Hashable`, and so on.